# How to display image from hive binary field using hive jdbc

Tags: java, hadoop, jdbc, hive, binary-data

I want to load and display image from hive binary field which was stored as binary from SQL Server Image field.

I have tried with couple of ways to solve this as follows

1. Extracting binary data from hive jdbc resultset as a string:

   Query: `select image from table_4 where imageId=12;`

   ```
   String image=res.getString(1);
   byte[] imageBytes=image.getBytes("UTF-8");
   ....
   ```

   written into output stream and saved as some jpg image. 
   but not able to display image because of unsupported file format.
2. Extracting binary data from hive jdbc resultset as a byte array:

   Query: `select image from table_4 where imageId=12;`

   ```
   byte[] imageBytes=res.getBytes(1);
   .....
   ```

   Getting Exception as Method not supported, HiveResulSet.getBytes.
3. Extracting binary data from hive jdbc resultset as a Blob:

   Query: `select image from table_4 where imageId=12;`

   ```
   Blob imageBlob=res.getBlob(1);
   .....
   ```

   Getting Exception as Method not supported, HiveResulSet.getBlob.
4. Extracting binary data from hive jdbc resultset as a InputStream i.e BinaryStream:

   Query: `select image from table_4 where imageId=12;`

   ```
   InputStream imageStream=res.getBinaryStream(1);
   byte[] imageBytes=IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
   ....
   ```

   written into output stream and saved as some jpg image. 
   but not able to display image because of unsupported file format.

Note: image is binary type in hive. We don't have any such type of binary type in java jdbc. That is why I'm trying to access that binary into string/byte array/input stream ... etc

Please help me how to access and display hive binary data as image using hive jdbc. If my way of doing is correct then help me out with different ways of encoding that can be able to display image content in supported file format.

Comment: How did you move SQL Server `image` data in hive?

Comment: using sqoop...moved sql server tables into hive.

Comment: _"We don't have any such type of binary type in java jdbc"_ -- **ARE YOU SERIOUS??** Class `java.sql.Types
` lists _BINARY_, _VARBINARY_, and _LONGVARBINARY_ ; and class `ResultSet` has methods `getBytes()` and `getBinaryStream()`

Comment: What matters is the way your **Hive JDBC driver** maps the BINARY data type. What have you tried: the Apache Type-3 driver? the Cloudera Type-4 driver? the DataDirect driver (bundled with Oracle, IBM, MicroStrategy etc.) ?

Comment: Did you make sure that the binary data inside SQL Server is the same as the binary data inside Hive *(based on hexa representation for instance)* and Sqoop did not screw up the import?

Comment: As per my understanding both the binaries are not same...because hive encoding format is differ with sql server...how to make same binary copied using sqoop??@Samson Scharfrichter

Comment: I'm using Apache type 3 driver ... and using Mapr distribution of hadoop@Samson Scharfrichter